# a or the - in the sentence: or maybe i'm just copy pasting from the website i've just came across

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I'm having trouble understanding what will sound more correct in the sentence when i'm describing some software functionality to a user and i'm what i could be doing with it.

Would it be "A website i just came across" or "THE website i've just came across" in the following sentence:

> I start typing or maybe i'm copy pasting from the website i've just came across.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I've read through this question a couple of times, but I can't really understand what you're asking for. Might you rephrase and clarify?

Comment: It's a capital "I".

Comment: I'd use 'a' there as it's unspecified to the addressee and only-just-discovered to the addresser. 'The' really requires prior context, perhaps "I've been looking all over the internet. The website I've just come across ..." (the addressee has some familiarity with the context.)

Comment: Idiomatically, indefinite article *(**a**)* is more common for your exact context, but you can validly use a range of determiners, including ***some, this, that*** as well as the definite article *(**the**)*. So really it's a stylistic choice, or POB question.